# Parsing and outputting file as CSV in Python

Tags: python, parsing, csv, text

I am trying to parse a text file which has the following format :

```
+++++
line1
line2
<<<<<
+++++
rline1
rline2
<<<<<
```

where, `+++++` means start of record and `<<<<<` means end of record.

Now I want to output the whole texts into csv in the following format:

```
line1, line2
rline1, rline2
```

I am trying sth like this:

```
lines =['+++++', 'line1', 'line2', '<<<<<', '+++++', 'rline1', 'rline2', '<<<<<']
output_lines =[]

for line in lines:
    if (line == "+++++") or not(line == "<<<<<") :
        if (line == "<<<<<"):
            output_lines.append(line)
            output_lines.append(",")

print (output_lines)
```

I am not sure how to move forward from here.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv

lines =['+++++', 'line1', 'line2', '<<<<<', '+++++', 'rline1', 'rline2', '<<<<<']

# remove the +++++s, so that only the <<<<<s indicate line breaks
cleaned_list = [ x for x in lines if x is not "+++++" ]

# separate at <<<<<s
rows = [list(group) for k, group in groupby(cleaned_list, lambda x: x == "<<<<<") if not k]

f = open('result.csv', 'wt')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
finally:
    f.close()

print open('result.csv', 'rt').read()
```

Comment: Nice use of groupby, but you might want to add a little description of just what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Collect lines in nested loops until the end-of-record marker, and write out the resulting list to a CSV file:

```
import csv

with open(inputfilename) as infh, open(outputfilename, 'w', newline='') as outfh:
    writer = csv.writer(outfh)
    for line in infh:
        if not line.startswith('+++++'):
            continue

        # found start, collect lines until end-of-record
        row = []
        for line in infh:
            if line.startswith('<<<<<'):
                # found end, end this inner loop
                break
            row.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

        if row:
            # lines for this record are added to the CSV file as a single row
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The outer loop takes lines from the input file, but skips anything that doesn't look like the start of a record. Once a start is found, a second, inner loop draws *more* lines from the file object, and as long as they do *not* look like the end of the record, adds them to a list object (sans the line separator).

When the end of a record is found, the inner loop is ended, and if any lines were collected in the `row` list, it is written out to the CSV file.

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import sys
>>> demo = StringIO('''\
... +++++
... line1
... line2
... <<<<<
... +++++
... rline1
... rline2
... <<<<<
... ''')
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> for line in demo:
...     if not line.startswith('+++++'):
...         continue
...     row = []
...     for line in demo:
...         if line.startswith('<<<<<'):
...             break
...         row.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
...     if row:
...         writer.writerow(row)
... 
line1,line2
13
rline1,rline2
15
```

The numbers after the written lines are the number of bytes written, as reported by `writer.writerow()`.